# f.select doesn't show entered value in Rails 4 when editing a record in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to build my Edit record form.

The record I'm editing is an address.

I am having trouble getting the f.select menu to display the record in the @address.state column.  It puts all the other address info the respective input fields as defaults...but not the f.select.  With the f.select it defaults back to "Alabama" (the first state).  How can I get the menu to stay set on the state that is recorded in the database?

Here's my code:

```
    <%=    f.select :state, options_for_select(us_states),  { :class => 'chosen-select ', :style => 'height:30px', }, {:value => @project.state} %>
```

Comment: You don't use options for select here - just an array. `f.select :state, us_states`.

Comment: That works!  If you'd like to "answer" the question I can give you credit.